# Is it worth it to use multiple threads to read a CSV file?

Tags: multithreading, performance, csv, parsing, optimization

I've just noticed that the [Fast C++ CSV Reader](https://github.com/ben-strasser/fast-cpp-csv-parser/blob/master/csv.h), a popular header-only library on GitHub, defaults to using multiple threads to read a CSV file from disk, and was wondering how come this could be beneficial with typical hardware.

Let's assume the file is located on a single HDD or SSD.

- It seems that disk bandwidth is maximized with a sequential read.
- A single thread, occupying a single core, should be able to pull off enough computation and memory writes to keep up with the bandwidth of an SSD (3.5 MB/sec for a Samsung 960 these days, > 10 GB/sec even for DDR3 on a single socket, and easily > 25 GB/sec with reasonable consumer hardware today)

I'm not even sure 2 threads, with the effect of HyperThreading, should really be much help.

Am I miscalculating, or is multi-thread CSV reading relevant only for more exotic scenarios (RAM mimicking a disk partition / file cached in memory / multiple disks etc.)?

Comment: Maybe its optimized for reading from a network? If not, its way over-engineered.

Comment: @rustyx: In its defense I'll say you can disable the use of multiple threads using a preprocessor define.